# Trying to make a grid with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

In my attempts to understand flex i decided i want to make a grid. Here's a general layout image for that:

[image]

The idea is that there's

- a) a sidebar
- b) a sticky header under which the main containers crolls
- c) a main container that holds the main data
- d) items that are sized depending on their content placed on a grid

To implement the sticky header i created did the following:

```
<div>
<div class="stickyHeader"></div>
<div class="contentscroll"></div>
</div>
```

Where

```
.stickyHeader{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.178);
}
```

and

```
.contentscroll{
    overflow: scroll;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* justify-content: flex-start; */
    flex-flow:row wrap;
}
```

The issue is that the flex elements are trying to fill the 100% of the main container and therefore the page looks very different if i've got one item element vs 6 ( meaning that the space between the item elements and the sticky header seems variable when i really want it to be a specific distance.

Thanks a lot, you can find the entire code here:

https://jsbin.com/wivudiqisa/edit?html,css,output

Comment: If you're trying to make a "grid" then use the `gridd` css i.e .`display: grid`

Comment: the issue with that is browser support though..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you mean with "sticky header seems variable" but you can distribute the flex Elements like this:

```
.contentscroll{
    ...
    justify-content: space-between;
    ...
}

.contentitemcontainer {
    ...
    width:20%;
    ...
}
```

I found this guide helpful: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

The support for Css Grid has greatly improved and you don't need to hack you way into building a grid! It has more than 90% browser support, so let's start using Grids

I have put together an article that covers precisely that and where to use grid and when to use flex [here](https://dioxmio.medium.com/grid-vs-flexbox-which-one-should-you-be-using-471cb955d3b5) if you want to know more info

Comment: what about mobile